# Shifted stacked ybar plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, diagrams, bar-chart, ybar

When using a stacked ybar plot, each stacked column begins at y=0
. I would like to vertically shift the stacked column of Data B, so that its lower end aligns horizontally with the upper end of the stacked column of Data A (here: y = 2 + 1 + 2.5 = 5.5).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[ybar stacked]
            
            % Data A
            \addplot[] coordinates {(1,2) (2,0)};
            \addplot[] coordinates {(1,1) (2,0)};
            \addplot[] coordinates {(1,2.5) (2,0)};
            
            % Data B
            \addplot[] coordinates {(1,0) (2,1)};
            \addplot[] coordinates {(1,0) (2,1.5)};
            
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is there an easy solution for this?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but using `pgfplots` you should set the `compat` option to some current version, for example by placing `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}` in the preable, to make sure that you use the most current features of the package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, with the coordinates you show you overdefine the diagram. It should be sufficient to give the following, which will automatically result in the desired output (if I got right what you say of which I am not fully sure):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[ybar stacked, ymin=0, xtick={1,2}]
            
            % Data A
            \addplot[] coordinates {(1,2)};
            \addplot[] coordinates {(1,1)};
            \addplot[] coordinates {(1,2.5)};
            
            % Data B
            \addplot[] coordinates {(2,1)};
            \addplot[] coordinates {(2,1.5)};
            
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]